# SvelteKit Server Side Authentication with Supabase not creating cookie with Token

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I'm trying to implement Server Side Authentication with Supabase and Sveltekit. I followed the [Quickstart Guide](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-sveltekit) and was able to do authentication client-side. (preventDefault on the submit event and do client-side POST request).

But when trying to do the same thing Server-Side , the auth cookie with the token is not created. Here's the logic:

```js
// src/routes/login/+page.server.ts

import type { PostgrestResponse } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { supabaseClient } from '$lib/supabaseClient';
import type { Database } from '$lib/types/database.types';
import type { PageLoad } from './$types';
import type { PageServerLoad, Actions } from './$types';
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const actions: Actions = {
  'login-with-password': async ({ request }) => {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const email = formData.get('email');
    const password = formData.get('password');
    console.log(email, password);
    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithPassword({ email, password });
    console.log(data);
    if (error) {
      return {
        status: 500,
        body: {
          error: error.message
        }
      };
    }
    throw redirect(302, '/');
    return { success: true };
  }
};
```

`data` seems to hold the correct response, with token and everything, but that's not persisted as a cookie.

[https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/gkatsanos/client](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/gkatsanos/client)

Answer (score 0):

George!
I know it's probably too late, but I just happened upon your question. If this isn't helpful for you, maybe it can help somebody else.

For my Sveltekit + Supabase login, I'm just calling

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
  email,
  password
});
```

from the client, as documented in the Supabase JS Reference [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signinwithpassword). I know you said you got login working with the client, and I'm assuming this is what you meant. So, maybe the session information is just not being passed through to the client from your +page.server.ts page?

It might be better to use an "API route" like `src/routes/api/login` with code like:

```
export const POST = async ({ request }: RequestEvent) => {
  const reqData = await request.json();
  const errors = {};
  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
    email: reqData.email,
    password: reqData.password
  });
    
  if (error) {
    console.log('LOG IN ERROR:', error);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ 
      error: 'Log In Failed'}));
    }
    
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
}
```

Have you tried using this approach, which is detailed in the Sveltekit documentation [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server)? Vercel also has pretty nice documentation [here](https://vercel.com/docs/beginner-sveltekit/endpoints#creating-an-endpoint). I am using this for email and password signup, but successful signup means they get an email with a magiclink. You may very well run into the same issue using this method.

I have been using Svelte for a few years, and trying out Sveltekit 1.0 is definitely requiring some time and effort for me. I hope this is helpful, and I'm really interested in how you solve this problem--and maybe the 'why' behind the implementation you're working on.

All the best.